# I have deleted Nginx directories

Tags: nginx, ubuntu-16.04

This is kind of embarrassing but I have accidentally deleted all directories in `/usr/share/nginx`, that is there where the html directory for serving static pages is.

I have **NOT** deleted the config files. And to my knowlegde all the files that was deleted were default.
So my question is: what where those directories and that is the simplest way of restoring them without overwriting the conf files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This action is not matter, check nginx default config files

default;

```
mkdir -p /usr/share/nginx/html
echo 'Hello World' > /usr/share/nginx/html/index.html
```

Comment: Yeah, I figured out that it works without those directories as I did something similar to what you are proposing, but would still like to know the directories. If not for me, then for some other poor chap as it seems to be quite hard to find it using google. I couldn't at least.